# Filter to track time spent by an user in each page in a spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, appfuse, user-tracking

I am working on a spring application in which I want to track the users time spent on each page. I am planning to do it via Spring filters. Is there a spring filter that intercepts each and every page request?

Or if you know any better ways of doing or an API that already does this which I can plug-in into my application - please suggest.

Comment: If the reason for this is "internet marketing" then you should do it via Google Analytics (or something similar).

Comment: Any server-side filter won't help you since you want to measure how much time a user spent on a page, not how much it took to load it/render it. See @cherouvim comment above.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: Well it's probably doable on the server as well by linking a pageview to a previous pageview (by also associating user by a cookie) and possibly losing the view time of the last clicked page. But this would be hard to get right especially if the reason for this is analytics.

Comment: @cherouvim No this is not for internet marketing, it is an internal application. The purpose is track the time spent by each user on different pages during the session(from log-in to log-out).

Comment: OK but note that you can still use analytics for internal applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Spring [`org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) interface. It is a normal bean with an special interface.

Read the [Spring reference chapter 15.4.1 Intercepting requests - the HandlerInterceptor interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

The other (spring independend) way would be implmenting a servelt filter, but there you do not have spring support for example for easy access to other beans.